# Calculate range count in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

Apparently before Swift 3, a `Range<String.Index>` had a `count` property. While migrating to Swift 3 I noticed that this `count` property is now gone. How do I calculate the distance between 2 `String.Index`es in Swift 3?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of Swift 3, all index calculations are done by the collection itself,
compare [SE-0065 – A New Model for Collections and Indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md) on Swift evolution.

Example:

```
let string = "abc 1234 def"
if let range = string.range(of: "\\d+", options: .regularExpression) {
    let count = string.distance(from: range.lowerBound, to: range.upperBound)
    print(count) // 4
}
```

Actually, `String` is *not* a collection in Swift 3, but it has those methods
as well and they are forwarded to the strings `CharacterView`.
You get the same result with

```
let count = string.characters.distance(from: range.lowerBound, to: range.upperBound)
```

As of Swift 4, strings are collections (again).

Comment: Has this changed or become simpler in Swift 5?

Comment: @meaning-matters: No. – There is a [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0265-offset-indexing-and-slicing.md) which is (as I understand it) meant to ease the index/offset calculations, but this is still [discussed](https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0265-offset-based-access-to-indices-elements-and-slices/29596).